# Resetting a timer in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I realize that someone has asked this question before, but I found the answer wasn't working for me.
I have some code like this.

```
fire_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(fire_event, 900)

while exit:
 for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif event.type == fire_event:
            index_rand = random.randint(0, len(enemies) - 1)
 if something:
    pygame.time.set_timer(fire_event, 200)
```

Followed by the main loop in which I want to change the time. Using the line `pygame.time.set_timer(fire_event, 500)` didn't work for me. I was able to stop the timer by replacing the value with 0, but I seem to be unable to reset the timer.

Comment: Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your main loop is the issue, since it's checking for `exit` (being True), but the window-closing test seems to be on `run`.

```
while exit:                           # <-- HERE, should this be "while run"?
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
```

In any event, here's a minimum example of changing and stopping a timer.

```
import pygame

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH    = 400
WINDOW_HEIGHT   = 400

### initialisation
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ) ) 
pygame.display.set_caption( "Timers" )

# Events
USER_EVENT = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer( USER_EVENT, 2000 )
event_count = 0

### Main Loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
while not done:

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True
        elif ( event.type == USER_EVENT ):
            print( "USER-EVENT" )
            event_count += 1
            if ( event_count < 10 ):
                pygame.time.set_timer( USER_EVENT, 500 )
            else:
                print( "Timer Cancelled" )
                pygame.time.set_timer( USER_EVENT, 0 )

    # Update the window, but not more than 60fps
    window.fill( (0,0,0) ) # Paint it black
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Clamp FPS
    clock.tick_busy_loop(60)

pygame.quit()
```